# how to copy & paste data value in different worksheets using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from workbook1 and pasting to workbook2 as per there valves if the valve is not same as previous than create a new sheet in the workbook and start pasting valve in the new sheet and do until did not find blank row in workbook1.

```
Sub icopy()

Dim LastRow As Long, Limit2 As Long, c As Long, d As Long, erow As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, 
wb1 As Workbook

If Is_WorkBook_Open("test.xlsx") Then
    Set wb = Workbooks("test.xlsx")
Else
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Data\test.xlsx")
End If

Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'wb.Close

MsgBox LastRow

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If sh1.Cells(i, 1) = sh1.Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
        If (i = 2) Then
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Data\Data1.xlsx")
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = sh1.Cells(2, 1)
        Set sh2 = wb1.ActiveSheet.Name
    End If
    sh1.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy
    erow = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    'sh2.Cells(erow, 1).Select
    sh2.Cells(erow, 3).Paste
    sh2.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
Else
    MsgBox i
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = sh1.Cells(i + 1, 1)
End If

Next i
    'erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
    ' ActiveSheet.Paste
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'ActiveWorkbook.Close
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Function Is_WorkBook_Open(ByVal strWorkbookName As String) As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks(strWorkbookName)
   If Err Then
   Is_WorkBook_Open = False
Else
   Is_WorkBook_Open = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: you may want to add some screenshots of before and after scenarios

Comment: Maybe but not now, It can more than enough for me :)

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another. so data is like every entry of device as per date. there is more than 3000 device. if every device has separate sheet than it would be great for further work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I understand your valve data are *adjacent* (i.e. all same valve data are within one block of adjacent rows), you could consider the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub icopy()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim iRow As Long

    If Is_WorkBook_Open("test.xlsx") Then
        Set sh1 = Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Else
        Set sh1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Data\test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    End If

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Data\Data1.xlsx") ' open your target workbook
    With sh1
        iRow = 2
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            Do While iRow <= .Rows.Count
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=.Cells(iRow, 1).Value
                wb1.Sheets.Add(After:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)).name = .Cells(iRow, 1).Text
                With .Resize(, 3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    .copy Destination:=wb1.Sheets(.Cells(iRow, 1).Text).Range("a1")
                    iRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows(.Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows.Count).row + 1
                End With
            Loop
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First, you are filtering the data, then copy to the target sheet, but the problem is when I code is running is saying script out of range when irow is 2. that means there is some issue in my understanding would like to tell me what I did wrong                                                     
                                                                  
    {.copy Destination:=wb1.Sheets(.Cells(iRow, 1).Value).Range("a1")}

Comment: unfortunately, without any sight of your data layout is hard to help you out

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16wQkLuwF-tLzfqTiSY0TgkLiEI3Z7l6h/view?usp=sharing Something like this.

Comment: I wouldn’t open any file from the web. Add some relevant screenshots

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1My-u6HNy4HO-Sg--lgkto4Hc-j_V1ARz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: seen the shot. now some explanation is needed

Comment: since your "valve" data are big numbers, its `.Value`ing would implicitly trying to convert them to some exponential number format. So I substituted `.Value` with `.Text`. If it solves your question you may consider marking answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: indeed great help... I really appreciated

Comment: I tried but... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1My-u6HNy4HO-Sg--lgkto4Hc-j_V1ARz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: to accept the solution you just _"click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in"_. Thank you!